# Is forced movement mandatory for allies?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

I understand from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13221/dd-4e-required-forced-movement) that the initiator of forced movement can choose not to move a target if they wish, but if the target is an ally, is the ally able to choose not to be moved?

I am going to start playing a Bard soon, and I thought that it would be good to know in advance whether my party members can veto all of the sliding that they will inevitably undergo. I don't plan to abuse my power, but if push comes to shove (no pun intended), it's nice to know who gets the final decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, but beware of thrown dice, hurled pizza, and no-one being willing to give you a ride.**

While forced movement is forced movement, beware inflicting it on PCs. Instead, establish game-plans in advance and *explain* what you're doing. By explaining and *allowing* them to veto, you will promote party cohesion and actually perform better tactically (by not foiling the other plans of the party members.)

Comment: There are cases when party members do need shoving. Like when the murderous rogue is trying to off the combatant who just surrendered and is being questioned.

Comment: @EugeneKatz in that case you have party issues :)

Comment: @EugeneKatz It's funny you mention that, my group had that exact thing happen (and it was the rogue that did it, too).

Comment: @waxeagle It's not necessarily party issues. He was just playing the character. That can easily get over the line to a player just wanting to cause trouble, but in this case it was just one of the values that the character held. Annoying, yes, but not malicious.