# Using flail expertise with powers that push/pull/slide

Tags: dnd-4e, combat

I am playing a battlemind with flail expertise.  This allows me to knock prone an opponent instead of sliding them.  Is sliding specific to just powers that say slide or is push and pull included as a slide?

Comment: Welcome to the site!
Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13221/4089

Answer (score 6):

**No, push and pull do not count as slide.**

From the RC, p211:

> **Forced Movement**
>   Certain powers and effects allow a creature to move a target forcibly, whether the target is willing or unwilling. ... The three kinds of forced movement are pull, push, and slide.

Push & pull are not special types of slide; push, pull, and slide are all types of forced movement.

However, here are 2 feats you may want to look at:

> **Dragging Flail** (heroic tier feat from *Martial Power 1* page 133)
>   **Prerequisites:** Dex 15, fighter
>   **Benefit:** Whenever you use a flail to knock an enemy prone, you can also slide that enemy 1 square.

and

> **Lashing Flail** (paragon tier feat from *Martial Power 2* page 14)
>   **Prerequisite:** 11th level, any martial class
>   **Benefit:** Whenever you use a flail to hit an enemy with a melee basic attack, you can slide that enemy 1 square.